# What is an attribute Node

Tags: xml

What is an attribute Node in the XPath Data Model?  When would a particular Node become an Attribute Node ?

If anybody can provide an example of the attribute Nodes that would be very helpful.

Comment: Beast, You need to learn some basics of XML. This would be more useful for you than asking isolated questions.

Comment: Dimitre. I recently started to learn XML,XPath and XSLT. If you can provide me any good links to learn XML than it would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Beast, I can provide you with links to good XSLT/XPath books, but they all suppose that you already know what XML is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. One final request would be If you can reply to question I asked against the answer provided by cthulhu than it would be a great help to me.

Comment: Beast ?????? I don't understand your request -- could you, please, rephrase?

Comment: My question is, Is it possible to create the attribute node with out any parent element? If possible can you provide one example of it ?

Comment: Beast, yes -- this is possible in XSLT 2.0+. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP has clarified in a comment that his question is:

*Is it possible to create the attribute node with out any parent element?*

**Yes, in XSLT 2.0 one can write:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAttr" as="attribute()">
  <xsl:attribute name="x">y</xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="$vAttr"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t/>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t x="y"/>
```

**So, the attribute is created as a standalone item that hasn't any parent element. Then, we can copy an instance of it onto any element**.

Answer (score 3):

It is a node which holds an attribute value of the all the matched attributes. For example, if you have the following tag:

```
<tag name="foo">
    <child>Bar</child>
</tag>
```

then the XPath query `//@name` will return "foo" as a result. If there are *n* tags with that attribute, it will fetch all of the *n* attributes' values.

The attribute node itself consists of two parts - name and value. Hence, in the example above it would be `name="foo"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply cthulhu. In your example name is the attribute node and tag is the parent element.Is my understanding of your answer is correct  ? My another question is that is it possible to create the attribute node with out any parent element? If possible can you provide one example of it ?

Comment: @Beast - In XML you can't do this and there is no logic behind it. As Dimitre mentioned, you can make an attribute as a standalone object in XSLT to apply it on some elements which match a particular criteria, so when the document is transformed this attribute will be attached to the elements. But again, it has nothing to do with XML itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the XML below `bar="baz"` is an attribute with the name `bar` and the value `baz`:

```
<foo bar="baz"/>
```

An attribute doesn't "become" an attribute; it's either an attribute or not.

To access an attribute in XPath, you can use `@` (which is just a shortcut for the `attribute::` axis):

```
/foo/@bar
```

Also see these links for a little more information on XML basics.

- http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/core
- http://www.w3.org/XML/Datamodel.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But in the above example Is the foo would be called as an Attribute Node?

Comment: @Beast - No, `foo` is an element node.

Comment: @Beast - See my link to Datamodel.html above for more info on the different types of nodes.

Comment: In your example bar would be the name of the attribute node and baz would be its value and foo would be the parent element for the attribute node. Am I right? As per the link(http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#AttributeNode) it also suggest the attribute nodes with out any parent element can you provide me one of the examples of it.